# how to serve optimised images in magento if the images are hosted on differente server?

Tags: product-images, optimization

I know there are plenty of extensions (free and paid) whcih optimises image before serving it. but the issue for me is, i am using stockinthechannel for our images and data, and we import images as link so none of the product image is hosted on our site.

is there any way we can optimise these images before serving on our site?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to optimise the images on the site you retrieve them from - stockinthechannel in this case. The server doesn't know anything about the images except for the URL, therefore it can't do anything. I'd recommend downloading the images and serving them from your own website, if your license allows that.